# How can I dismiss the on screen keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, dismiss

I am collecting user input with a `TextFormField` and when the user presses a `FloatingActionButton` indicating they are done, I want to dismiss the on screen keyboard.

How do I make the keyboard go away automatically?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.send),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            // send message
            // dismiss on screen keyboard here
            _controller.clear();
          });
        },
      ),
      body: new Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Example Text'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Here is the [recommended solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977554/8138591) in May 2021

Comment: sir can you please go through the below question relating to flutter . below link is my question link in stack overflow -----  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69640226/how-to-create-shapes-or-alphabets-by-joining-dots-join-dots-for-creating-shap  -------

Comment: I just did `keyboardType: TextInputType.none` for `CupertinoTextField & TextFormField`

Answer (score 913, accepted):

**For Flutter version 2 or latest :**

Since `Flutter 2` with null safety this is the best way:

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
```

Note: using old ways leads to some problems like keep rebuild states;

---

**For Flutter version < 2 :**

**As of Flutter v1.7.8+hotfix.2, the way to go is:**

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

[Comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7247#issuecomment-488307127) on PR about that:

> Now that #31909 (be75fb3) has landed, you should use
> `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` instead of
> `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode())`, since `FocusNode`s are
> `ChangeNotifiers`, and should be disposed properly.

-> **DO NOT** use `̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶F̶o̶c̶u̶s̶(̶F̶o̶c̶u̶s̶N̶o̶d̶e̶(̶)̶` anymore.

```
 F̶o̶c̶u̶s̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶o̶f̶(̶c̶o̶n̶t̶e̶x̶t̶)̶.̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶F̶o̶c̶u̶s̶(̶F̶o̶c̶u̶s̶N̶o̶d̶e̶(̶)̶)̶;̶
```

Read more about [the `FocusScope` class in the flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusScope-class.html).

Comment: The problem I have been experiencing is when leaving a text field to open up the camera, the keyboard is not always dismissed and overlaps the camera.  This solution does in fact remove the focus, BUT then the focus returns to the text field and the problem persists. Moving the focus to an unused FocusNode solves this.

Comment: If this solution didn't fix your error, you can add  "await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200))" before send to another page.

Comment: my issue was i put 'focusnode: FocusNode()' in ui. i removed it and put this code. Worked!

Comment: Thanks for your great solution. But I have a question about it. If I use FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(); solution, should I dispose of it in dispose method?

Comment: @Aaydin Not sure exactly what your use case is. I suggest you to just experiment / test and see the result ;-)

Answer (score 341):

**Note:** This answer is outdated. [See the answer for newer versions of Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56946311/1483676).

You can dismiss the keyboard by taking away the focus of the `TextFormField` and giving it to an unused `FocusNode`:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

Comment: Where would you implement this code?  In the TextFormField; maybe after `onChanged:` or in the action of your custom button?

Comment: @CharlesJr I do it in the action of my button.

Comment: you can use my package if you want :) https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions

Comment: This is before Flutter v1.7.8 - see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56946311/8696915 which gives `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()`

Comment: Don't do this if you have access to .unfocus() since it'll cause a memory leak. That new FocusNode() will never get cleaned up.
See comment about .unfocus()

Comment: What I dont like about that is the creation of FocusNodes. and since you are not disposing it so its staying in memory which can result in memory leaks. The best alternative is 

FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

Comment: It triggers 2 renders

Answer (score 164):

Solution with FocusScope doesn't work for me.
I found another:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: Calling this doesn't hide the keyboard for me. Should it work on both Android and iOS?

Comment: Worked for me on iOS (12.1, iPhone 5s) and Android (Pixel 3)

Comment: Where do you put this? I tried just adding it as the first bit of code in the app and it didnt do anything.

Comment: What do you mean - "the first bit of code"? Insert it in `build` method for example.

Comment: is there an equivalent for this for the numeric keybaord?

Comment: Actually, I haven't faced with such issue. Doesn't this solution work with numeric?

Comment: This is the only way I was able to hide keyboard on Android, when the focus is inside a webview (webview_flutter).
Thanks

Comment: It triggers 2 renders

Comment: I used it in onClick function. It worked as I expected on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 106):

For Flutter 1.17.3 (stable channel as of June 2020), use

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
```

Comment: Tested and worked for Flutter: 1.24.0. and iOS 14.0 and Android Version 11 simulators.

Comment: Works well. With null-safety, use optional chaining on `primaryFocus` as follows:
`FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();`

Comment: this work for me  for flutter version: 2.0.2

Answer (score 40):

Following code helped me to hide keyboard

```
   void initState() {
   SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
   super.initState();
   }
```

Comment: For me, this worked better than the solution to add FocusScope.of(context).unfocus() as that solution put me into a loop of the keyboard being shown and hidden

Comment: This works the best for me.  I had a keyboard open from another screen and I think focus was in a weird state so only this method worked.  Thank YOU!!!!

Comment: This is much more elegant that the previous solutions. And most importantly, this can be wrapped in override `dispose` method to guarantee whenever the widget is disposed (e.g. very useful in dialog) , the on screen keyboard input will be closed appropriately.

Answer (score 32):

To dismiss the keyboard (1.7.8+hotfix.2 and above) just call the method below:

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Once the **FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()** method already check if there is focus before dismiss the keyboard it's not needed to check it. But in case you need it just call another context method:  `FocusScope.of(context).hasPrimaryFocus`

Answer (score 28):

Looks like different approaches for different version. I am using Flutter v1.17.1 and the below works for me.

```
onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
       currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

As in Flutter everything is a widget, I decided to wrap the `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` approach in a short utility widget.

Just create the `KeyboardHider` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// A widget that upon tap attempts to hide the keyboard.
class KeyboardHider extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates a widget that on tap, hides the keyboard.
  const KeyboardHider({
    required this.child,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// The widget below this widget in the tree.
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Now, you can wrap any widget (very convenient when using a good IDE) with the `KeyboardHider` widget, and then when you tap on something, the keyboard will close automatically. It works well with forms and other tappable areas.

```
class SimpleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardHider(
      /* Here comes a widget tree that eventually opens the keyboard,
       * but the widget that opened the keyboard doesn't necessarily
       * takes care of hiding it, so we wrap everything in a
       * KeyboardHider widget */
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          },
          child:Container(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: new TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Example Text'),
    ),
  ), })
```

try this on tap gesture

Answer (score 22):

None of the above solutions don't work for me.

Flutter suggests this - 
Put your widget inside **new GestureDetector()** on which tap will hide keyboard and onTap use **FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode())**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widget = new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
            body: new Container(
                height:500.0,
                child: new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                    },
                    child: new Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child:  new Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

                            children: [
                                new TextField( ),
                                new Text("Test"),                                
                            ],
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    );

    return widget;
}}
```

Answer (score 21):

For me, the Listener above App widget is the best approach I've found:

```
Listener(
  onPointerUp: (_) {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
      currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Test App',
    theme: theme,
    ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: This worked for me in iOS, I don't know it is right way to do it.

Comment: It worked in iOS, But we loose the paste functionality ! As soon as we tap & hold in textbox, paste option appears but hides when we try to tap on it.

Comment: Indeed this makes the paste functionality no longer work. Use the approach with `GestureDetector` to fix this

Answer (score 19):

This may simplify the case. Below code will work only if keyboard is open

```
if(FocusScope.of(context).isFirstFocus) {
 FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to do this is with the onTapOutside method that TextField provides:

```
onTapOutside: (PointerDownEvent event) {
   FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
},
```

Comment: Nice one, working fine.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `unfocus()` method from `FocusNode` class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode = new FocusNode(); //1 - declare and initialize variable

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.send),
        onPressed: () {
            _focusNode.unfocus(); //3 - call this method here
        },
      ),
      body: new Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          focusNode: _focusNode, //2 - assign it to your TextFormField
          decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Example Text'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Hi! It would be best if you could [edit] your answer to add just a little more context to your answer.

Comment: Yes, it removes the focus if tapping on an specific widget. Can't add it to every widget on my app.

Comment: Tapping on a widget is just one way to call `unfocus` method. If you don't want to spam this on your app you can use a different way, like the `TextFormField` change event or a reactive pattern, it depends on your app's architecture.

Answer (score 10):

To dismiss keyboard when TextField or some widget loses focus you can do this:

```
TextField(
      onTapOutside: (event) {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        }
      },
);
```

Answer (score 8):

To summarize, this is a working solution for Flutter 1.17:

Wrap your Widget like this:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: FocusScope.of(context).unfocus,
        child: YourWidget(),
);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

if you use CustomScrollView, just put,

```
keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
```

Answer (score 7):

In flutter 3.7.2 worked, wrap you Scaffold inside GestureDetector to dismiss keyboard when tap somewhere outside.

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
      SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod<void>('TextInput.hide');
   },
   child: Scaffold(),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your widget with "GestureDetector", then assign "FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()" to its onTap function

```
GestureDetector(
 onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
 child: child,
);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: You should debug and see whether onTap function is triggered or not. Having other tap listeners fore/back ground of GestureDetector, may be the case for you.

Answer (score 6):

Call this function when you needed

```
  void hideKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
      FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
      if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

====== Dismiss the keyboard **after clicking out of the TextField** =======

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),  //this will dismiss keyboard
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
               .........
```

====== Dismiss the keyboard **when scrolling the screen** =======

```
ListView(
            keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag, //this will dismiss
            children: [
               ..........
```

The ***SingleChildScrollView*** widget also have this property.

Answer (score 4):

add this code inside build widget

```
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

Comment: this solution is not recommended as it will cause a mess if you want to give textfield focus again.
below solution is prefect with if statement.
`closeKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
    var currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  }`

Answer (score 3):

```
_dismissKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
    this._dismissKeyboard(context);
    },
    child: new Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[/*...*/],
    ),
    ),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your keyboard still won't turn off , don't forget add focusNode to TextField. The above information was helpful, but forgetting to add focusNode bothered me a bit. Here an example.

```
TextField(
          focusNode: FocusNode(),
          textController: _controller,
          autoFocus: false,
          textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          onFieldSubmitted: (text) {},
          onChanged: (text) {},
          hint: 'Enter the code',
          hintColor: CustomColors.mediumGray,
          suffixAsset: _voucherController.text.length == 7
              ? Assets.ic_approved_voucher
              : null,
          isIcon: false,
          isObscure: false,
          maxLength: 7,
        )



closeKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
    var currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _keyboardVisible = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        closeKeyboard(context);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: double.maxFinite,
            child: _buildUI(vm)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

`FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());`

And you can use this `onTap` of `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // THIS FOCUS SCOPE WILL CLOSE THE KEYBOARD
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    forgotPasswordAPI(emailController.text);
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also declare a focusNode for you textfield and when you are done you can just call the unfocus method on that focusNode
and also dispose it

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

/// declare focus
  final FocusNode _titleFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _titleFocus.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.send),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            // send message
            // dismiss on screen keyboard here

            _titleFocus.unfocus();
            _controller.clear();
          });
        },
      ),
      body: new Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          focusNode: _titleFocus,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Example Text'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created this function to my base code, so far works well!!

```
void hideKeyword(BuildContext context) {
  FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
  if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
    currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');`. It will close/dismiss the keyboard when the screen loads.

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First Connect the **TextField** with **focusNode**

```
 TextField(
focusNode: focusNode),
```

now for show/open the keyboard call

```
focusNode.requestFocus();
```

and for hide/dismiss keyboard call

```
 focusNode.unfocus();
```

and if you want to know keyboard is visible or not at that time check the belew condition

final **keyBoardVisible** = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;

here **keyBoardVisible** value is true if keyboard is visible and false for dismissed keyboard

Answer (score 1):

FocusScope.of(context).unfocus() has a downside when using with filtered listView.
Apart from so many details and concisely, use keyboard_dismisser package in https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_dismisser will solve all the problems.

Comment: please follow[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: What is the downside?

Answer (score 1):

FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); doesn't work.

This code works for me at flutter ver 2.2.3 and null safety.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.focusManager.primaryFocus?.unfocus()
```

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20227#issuecomment-512860882

For example, put this code in MyAppState to apply hide keyboard when touch outside for whole app.

```
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () =>
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.focusManager.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: getTheme(),
    home: _body(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a TextEditingController.
at the begining,

```
    final myController = TextEditingController();
     @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

and in the on press event,

```
onPressed: () {
            myController.clear();}
```

this will dismiss the keybord.

Comment: It only clears the controller's text. It doesn't unfocus the TextField.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `TextField(maxLines: null)` and just want to show `Done` button ON the screen keyboard to hide it, the code below works.

```dart
TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    maxLines: null,
)
```

Side note: why in the first place doesn't the keyboard show `Done` button? The reason is found in [*the implementation of `TextField`*](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/TextField.html):

```dart
keyboardType = keyboardType ?? (maxLines == 1 ? TextInputType.text : TextInputType.multiline),
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a easy way.

set  keyboardType: TextInputType.none,

TextField(
autofocus: true,
keyboardType: TextInputType.none,

```
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: '',
    ),
    controller: _controller,
    
  )
```

Comment: Does it work for barcode readers?