# How to hide soft input keyboard on flutter after clicking outside TextField/anywhere on screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, hide

Currently, I know the method of hiding the soft keyboard using this code, by `onTap` methods of any widget.

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

But I want to hide the soft keyboard by clicking outside of TextField or anywhere on the screen. Is there any method in `flutter` to do this?

Comment: You can wrap your whole screen in a https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html and call above code in `onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());`

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. is there any touch event method, as tapping is not gonna resolve my issue. Keyboard is hiding on onTap method. I need to hide the keyboard frequently as I touch the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. why would tapping not solve your issue? You are tapping on the background or similar. When that happens, you call ...requestFocus...

Comment: I am working with TabBar and have search view box on each Tab screens. when I swipe from one tab to another then it doesn't swipe to another tab and comes back to same tab if keyboard is up on the screen or if there is text in TextField of SearchView. am having tab swiping issue mainly when keyboard is up otherwise tab swiping working fine.

Comment: How does that prevent you from applying my suggestion?

Comment: keyboard is hiding on onTap but still facing same issue, may be keyboard is hiding little late.

Comment: I see. Sorry, don't know how to work around that.

Comment: Try to use a `Listener` widget for access to direct touch events.

Comment: How can I add `Listener` widget, can you please gimme an example?

Comment: try the package I created :) https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions

Comment: MaterialApp(
         builder: (context, child) => GestureDetector( onTap: (){
       FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    }, child: child, ))

Answer (score 404, accepted):

You are doing it in the wrong way, just try this simple method to hide the soft keyboard. you just need to wrap your whole screen in the `GestureDetector` method and `onTap` method write this code.

```dart
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

Here is the complete example:

```dart
new Scaffold(
   body: new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
         FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
      child: new Container(
         //rest of your code write here
      ),
   ),
)
```

**Updated (May 2021)**

```dart
return GestureDetector(
   onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
   child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Body(),
   ),
);
```

This will work even when you touch the AppBar, `new` is [optional in Dart 2](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6#da82). `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus` will return the node that currently has the primary focus in the widget tree.

[Conditional access in Dart with null-safety](https://dart.dev/guides/language/cheatsheet#ab)

Comment: Actually only with a `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,` parameter `onTap` is always called. It didn't work on some taps for me without this parameter.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please check the updated answer for v1.17.1 (at least :)) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61986983/705842

Comment: Sometime gesture detector does not work on the whole screen then just wraps the scaffold inside GestureDetector Widget.

Comment: Gesture detector should be on Scaffold body directly, otherwise it won't work

Comment: onTapDown is better than onTap. `onTapDown: (_) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus()`

Comment: @Hardik "better" in what terms?

Comment: @KonstantinKozirev in onTapDown, it triggers the function as soon as we touch the screen unlike onTap where it triggers the function on lifting the finger making a tap gesture.

Comment: Please update the accepted answer to the latest and better solutions:

* `TextField` now has an `onTapOutside` callback parameter
* If you don't have control of the text field and you cannot pass any parameter you can use `TextFieldTapRegion` widget as a wrapper.

Answer (score 60):

### The Most Simplest Solution Yet

I've found the easiest way to do it,
now you can use `onTapOutside` in the TextField widget

```
 TextField(
       onTapOutside: (event) {
                  print('onTapOutside');
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                },)
```

This is called for each tap that occurs outside of the[TextFieldTapRegion] group when the text field is focused.

Comment: Just solved using this approach.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this behavior but this answer is the most solid one.

Comment: This is the cleanest and most straightforward approach, yet virtually invisible among GestureDetector answers. An editor should put this answer all the way up.

Comment: Such a simple solution, much better than the alternatives, and it actually works! Thank you!

Comment: Very clean and better approach. Should be the right answer! I think wrapping something into a gesture detector without the real need is not the right way of doing this.

Comment: I had edited your title to correct your "The Most Simplest Solutions" wrong English, but if you enjoy it like that, it's ok :)

Comment: this parameter exists even in `TextFormField` :)

Answer (score 55):

## Updated

Starting May 2019, `FocusNode` now has [`unfocus`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode/unfocus.html) method:

> Cancels any outstanding requests for focus.
>
> This method is safe to call regardless of whether this node has ever requested focus.

Use `unfocus` if you have declared a `FocusNode` for your text fields:

```dart
final focusNode = FocusNode();

// ...

focusNode.unfocus();
```

My original answer suggested `detach` method - use it only if you need to get rid of your `FocusNode` completely. If you plan to keep it around - use `unfocus` instead.

If you have not declared a `FocusNode` specifically - use `unfocus` for the `FocusScope` of your current context:

```dart
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

---

*See revision history for the original answer.*

Comment: `detach` is no longer available, I believe. I tried calling it, but it does not work - it says there's no function with that name.

Comment: @RodrigoVieira thank you for pointing that out. I removed outdated information from my post.

Answer (score 41):

Just as a small side note:

If you use `ListView` its `keyboardDismissBehavior` property could be of interest:

```dart
ListView(
  keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
  children: [],
)
```

---

Additionally, you can also use [TapRegion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TapRegion-class.html)

```dart
TapRegion(
  onTapOutside: (event) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
  child: // your sub-tree that triggered the keyboard
)
```

Comment: your small side note is big!

Comment: Thanks ! awesome note. Perfect solution for Searchdelegate.

Comment: Works also for SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 31):

Wrap whole screen in `GestureDetector` as

```
new Scaffold(

  body: new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // call this method here to hide soft keyboard
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
    child: new Container(
       -
       -
       -
        )
   )
```

Comment: Just for the records: Creating `FocusNode`s on demand without disposing them is likely to cause memory leaks...

Answer (score 27):

I've added this line

```
behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
```

to the GestureDetector and it seems to be working now as expected.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).calculatorAdvancedStageTitle),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 14,
            top: 8,
            right: 14,
            bottom: 8,
          ),
          child: Text('Work'),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Somehow the hittestbehaviour is needed for it to work in iOS.

Comment: This messes with VoiceOver behavior. You may want to add `excludeFromSemantics: true` to make sure assistive technologies don't see the entire screen as a single tappable block.

Answer (score 19):

As of Flutters latest version v1.7.8+hotfix.2, you can hide keyboard using unfocus() instead of requestfocus()

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()
```

so whenever you tap in the body part keyboard gets hidden

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: Container(...)
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I use Singlechildscrollview and if the empty spaces below are touched it doesn't work. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @Dharaneshvar the answer is: put your GestureDetecfor before Scaffold. Enjoy =)

Answer (score 14):

## *Update sept 2022 :: on flutter 3.0.2

if you have complex screen, i recommend  to use `Listener` instead.
here i face issue before :

[There is a lag/delay when catch the event on `GestureDetector` with `HitTestBehavior.opaque`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73632909/12838877)

documentation said:

> Rather than listening for raw pointer events, consider listening for
> higher-level gestures using GestureDetector

`GestureDetector` listening to high-level gesture. I think its caused some delay or lagging.

my workaround:

```
Listener(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onPointerDown: (_) {
     FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  },
  child: Scaffold()
```

this will be catch event when you tap anywhere.

Comment: This is the one that worked best for me. It behaves how you would expect when you scroll or tap anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

If you want the behavior to be accessible on any screen in your app, wrap MaterialApp with GestureDetector:

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Checking hasPrimaryFocus is necessary to prevent Flutter from throwing an exception when trying to unfocus the node at the top of the tree.**

(Originally given by James Dixon of the Flutter Igniter blog)

Comment: `unfocus` is called but nothing happen. The current focus not lost.

Comment: This version redraws your entire view heirarchy; whatever is inside the gestureDetector. I believe the issue is the currentFocus.unfocus() call. Use the selected answer above.

Comment: maybe try `onPanDown` instead of `onTap` or maybe another gesture

Answer (score 7):

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  child: rootWidget
)
```

Answer (score 7):

```dart
onPressed: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
},
```

This works for me.

Comment: where is it added? in GestureDetector?

Answer (score 7):

This will work in the latest flutter version.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
        currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
      primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
    ),
    home: LoginUI(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this "the right way", use Listener instead of GestureDetector.

GestureDetector will only work for "single taps", which isn't representative of all possible gestures that can be executed.

```
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (_) {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(...),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
child: Form(
    child: Column(
        children: [
            TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'User Name', hintText: 'User Name'),
                onTapOutside: (PointerDownEvent event) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_unUsedFocusNode);
                },
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

define focus Node

```
FocusNode _unUsedFocusNode = FocusNode();
```

override the onTapOutside method in TextFromField

```
onTapOutside: (PointerDownEvent event) {
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_unUsedFocusNode);
},
```

Edit:

```
Note: it will work in sdk Flutter 3.6.0-0.1.pre Dart SDK 2.19.0-374.1.beta
```

Answer (score 4):

Best for me.

I wrap since `Material App` because global outside touch

```
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
}
```

Resolve below,

I check Platform `iOS` only because `Android` can dismiss the keyboard the **back button**.

```
Listener(
  onPointerUp: (_) {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
      if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
          currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
      }
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
    home: MyHomePage(),
    ...
  ),
),
```

So happy your coding.

Flutter version

[image]

Comment: yeah, after a year, it works nicely on iOS...

Comment: its worked for me on ios , as u said adroid has back button. ( flutter version 3.0.5 )

Answer (score 3):

I just developed a small package to give any widget the kind of behavior you are looking for: [keyboard_dismisser on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_dismisser). You can wrap the whole page with it, so that the keyboard will get dismissed when tapping on any inactive widget.

Answer (score 3):

With Flutter 2.5 GestureDetector.OnTap hasn't worked for me.

Only this worked:

```
return GestureDetector(
      //keyboard pop-down
      onTapDown: (_) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      child: Scaffold(
```

Comment: Same. Only this works for me. Thanks.

Comment: This works thanks! But how do we make it work when the user presses the back button?

Answer (score 3):

**The simplest way** - just write some code in your `MaterialApp`'s `builder` method:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: const MyHomePage(),
    builder: (context, child) {
      // this is the key
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
        child: child,
      );
    },
 );
}
```

Then in all the pages it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `onTapOutside` now.

```
TextField(
    onTapOutside: (b) {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    }, 
),
```

Answer (score 2):

try this if you are on a stack

```
body: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
              },
              child: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Stack(children: [
                  _CustomBody(_),
                  Positioned(
                      bottom: 15, right: 20, left: 20, child: _BotonNewList()),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode focus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!focus.hasPrimaryFocus && focus.focusedChild != null) {
      focus.focusedChild.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
```

Comment: Write some details.

Comment: Write this code in your main.dart inside build function.So  that it will work for the whole application

Answer (score 2):

so easy solution for beginner here is the smoothest solution for you while you need to hide-keyboard  when user tap on any area of screen. hope its help you a lot.

**Step - 1 : you need to create this method in Global class,**

this method wrap you main widget into GestureDetector so when user tap outside the textfield it will hide keyboard automatically

```
Widget hideKeyboardWhileTapOnScreen(BuildContext context, {MaterialApp child}){

  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      if (Platform.isIOS) { //For iOS platform specific condition you can use as per requirement
        SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
        print("Keyboard Hide");
      }      
    },
    child: child,
  );
}
```

this method wrap you main widget into Listener so when user touch and scroll up it will hide keyboard automatically

```
Widget hideKeyboardWhileTapOnScreen(BuildContext context, {MaterialApp child}){
  return Listener(
    onPointerUp: (_) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
            currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
          print("Call keyboard listner  call");
        }
      }
    },
    child: child,
  );
}
```

**Step - 2 : here is how to use Global method**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
  return hideKeyboardWhileTapOnScreen(context,
    child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Scaffold(body: setAppbar())),
  );
}

Widget setAppbar2() {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.orange),
    home: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the hiding keyboard uses this

```
 onTapOutside: (e) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
```

textformField

```
   TextFormField( 
                  
                  onTapOutside: (e) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Enter your name'), ),
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true what maheshmnj said that from version v1.7.8+hotfix.2, you can hide keyboard using unfocus() instead of requestfocus().

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()
```

But in my case I was still presented with a lot of layout errors, as the screen I navigated to was not capable of handling the layout.

```
════════ Exception Caught By rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following JsonUnsupportedObjectError was thrown during paint():
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Infinity
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject  (dart:convert/json.dart:647:7)
#1      _JsonStringifier.writeMap  (dart:convert/json.dart:728:7)
#2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue  (dart:convert/json.dart:683:21)
#3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject  (dart:convert/json.dart:638:9)
#4      _JsonStringifier.writeList  (dart:convert/json.dart:698:9)
```

This was handled by inserting "***resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false***" in the receiving screens Scaffold()

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,   // HERE
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Receiving Screen "),
      ),
      body: Container(...)
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

```
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
```

You should check here https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/

Comment: It would be more useful if you could also add here the main points of your linked site.

Answer (score 1):

This is best

```
Scaffold(
body: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
   if (messageFocusNode.hasFocus) {
     messageFocusNode.unfocus();
 }
},
child: new Container(
   //rest of your code write here
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE NOVEMBER 2021**

According to the new flutter webview [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter):
Putting this piece of code inside the given full example will solve the keyboard dismiss the issue.

```
@override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
         // Enable hybrid composition.
         if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
   }
```

**Full example code:**

```
 import 'dart:io';
 import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

 class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
 }

 class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
         // Enable hybrid composition.
 if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
     );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your material app with GestureDetector and use below code to hide keyboard from anywhere in app.

```
GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
              currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          ...
        ),
      ),
```

It will hide keyboard from whole app

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the keyboard thoughout the app. Just by putting this code under builder in MaterialApp and if using Getx then under GetMaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
         builder: (context, child) => GestureDetector( onTap: (){
       FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    }, child: child, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Refreshindicaor -> triggerMode: RefreshIndicatorTriggerMode.anywhere