# How to hide the soft keyboard forever in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use an external keyboard in flutter, so I need to hide the keyboard while typing, how do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide soft input keyboard on flutter after clicking outside TextField/anywhere on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652897/how-to-hide-soft-input-keyboard-on-flutter-after-clicking-outside-textfield-anyw)

Comment: SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');