# How to Focus Out of a TextField in a Form with a Color Picker

Tags: flutter

I am implementing a Form where the user is able to write the title and the description of a course. In addition, the user should be able to choose a color for this particular course.

My goal is to unfocus from the currently edited Textfield when I am tapping somewhere else or clicking on the keyboard's back button.

I have found a similar post [How can I dismiss the on screen keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991968/how-can-i-dismiss-the-on-screen-keyboard/56946311#56946311) where they use `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` within a GestureDetector Widget.

Unfortunately, this is not working in my case.

P.S. I am on Flutter 1.17.2

```
   child: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            },
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _CourseTitelField(isEditing: isEditing),
                  _CourseDescriptionField(isEditing: isEditing),
                  _CourseColorSelection(
                      mainColor: _mainColor, tempMainColor: _tempMainColor),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, I will mention 2 I like

1. SystemChannels from `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

```dart
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

2. FocusScope

```dart
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

Answer (score 0):

On your function that calls the color picker, use the code below before calling the color picker. This will unfocus the keyboard.
So you will have something like this:

```
void chooseColor(){
 FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus(); //unfocus keyboard

 //add code to call color picker
 ...
}
```