# Flutter without keyboard and keep focus

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to have a text field which when having the focus does not show the virtual keyboard? I need this to be able to capture the result delivered by a physical barcode reader built into the smartphone.
I've seen solutions that recommend passing focus to another node, but that way it couldn't capture the barcode, and I've also seen that it can be used:

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod ('TextInput.hide');
```

But for some reason it doesn't hide the keyboard.

Comment: You can hide the keyboard whenever required and show it again using single statement

Comment: try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56946311/5665870](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56946311/5665870) if >= Flutter v1.7.8+hotfix.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this library [flutter_barcode_listener](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_listener)

It works like the following.

1. listen for physical keyboard raw key up event
2. filter out only 'REAL'
   characters (ASCII codes lower than 256, without special characters
   except enter)
3. on each new key check if previous key is older than
   bufferDuration, if it's older clear internal buffer
4. check if new key is enter key, if it is call onBarcodeScanned callback
   and clear buffer
5. if it's not enter key just append it to internal buffer;

In your code you can wrap the widgets that depends on the scanner data with the BarcodeKeyboardListener and it will look something like this:

```
child: BarcodeKeyboardListener(
        bufferDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        onBarcodeScanned: (barcode) {
          if (!visible) return;
          print(barcode);
          setState(() {
            _barcode = barcode;
          });
        },
        child: SomeWidget(
```

Comment: this is not working for me.