# Hide keyboard when click on device back button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When the keyboard is open I am clicking on the device back button keyboard is not hiding it is navigating to the previous page.

Comment: Have you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991968/how-can-i-dismiss-the-on-screen-keyboard

Comment: @naijab.com if keyboard is open then hide, if key board is not open then navigate to previous page.

Answer (score 2):

`FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` will close the keyboard, device back button is controlled by WillPopScope, you can do something like this

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async{
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        return false;
      },
        child: Scaffold(.....)
    );
```

Comment: if keyboard is not open then navigate to previous page

Comment: Just add a ```Navigator.pop(context)```
You can use ```MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom``` to check if keyboard is currently open or closed.

Answer (score 2):

`FocusScope.of(context).isFirstFocus` it returns true when keyboard has focus, This only works if your keyboard open.

```
if (FocusScope.of(context).isFirstFocus) {
     FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use the keyboard_visibility package to do this effectively, I've used it and it works like charm.

**To install**

```
dependencies:
  keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.2
```

**Usage**

```
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

bool keyBoardState;

@protected
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
      print(visible);
      keyBoardState = visible;
    },
  );
}
```

now before you call other page first check the keyBoardState is true or false then do your job.