# How do I dismiss the keyboard in TextFormfield flutter 2.0.1

Tags: flutter, flutter2.0

Hey how do I dismiss the keyboard here? I want the keyboard to dismiss when tapped outside the area.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
  child: TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    maxLength: 10,
    controller: widget._phoneController,
    onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
    inputFormatters: [
      //input type
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
        RegExp(r'[0-9]'),
      ),
    ],
    //how the text box is decorated
    decoration: buildInputDecoration(
        Icons.phone, 'Enter your 10 digit phone number'),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Here is a good answer that can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977554/11547064

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I dismiss the on screen keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991968/how-can-i-dismiss-the-on-screen-keyboard)

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your parent widget that spans the entire screen with a widget that can detect clicks. In the `onClick`,

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()
```

`FocusScope.of(context)` gets the currently focused node and `.unfocus()` unfocuses it.

This works because when the `TextFormField` is clicked, it consumes the click. So the parent widget's `onClick` is not triggered. So no unfocussing happens.

When we click outside, the parent widget consumes the click event, because none of its children consume it. Thus, the parent's `onClick` is triggered.

Below is an example. You can see a [demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/3a1bc66570f31e0bd381890121c68962?null_safety=true).
(Although, it's best to run it on a mobile device so you can see the on screen keyboard.)

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hide keyboard in TextFormField when touched outside'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('Clicked outside');
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  onTap: () => print('Clicked TextFormField'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me :)

```
  TextField(
        onSubmitted: (value) async {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
    })
```