# How to create Shapes or Alphabets by joining dots ?( Join Dots for creating shapes puzzle) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, shapes, puzzle

[image]I want an App for creating shapes by Joining dots.
How to create Shapes or Alphabets by joining dots ?( Join Dots for creating shapes
puzzle) in Flutter?

Sample Image

Comment: Do you mean painting dots? Need more details.

Comment: i had edit the question and add a image in it .i want an activity like that.Joining dots to create shapes.a puzzle for children